# casting data depends on data type in C

Tags: c, enums

defined below  struct:

```
enum DATATYPE {INT32, FLOAT, DOUBLE};
struct DATA{
    enum DATATYPE type;
    char buff[8];
};

struct DATA data; <==this data was set by other thread.
```

Then question is how to printf data easier?
I know the "switch" way.

```
switch (data.type) {
    case INT32:
        printf("%d", *(int*)buff);
        break;
    case FLOAT:
        printf("%f", *(float*)buff);
        break;
    case DOUBLE:
        printf("%lf", *(double*)buff);
        break;
}
```

But if there are many DATATYPEs, it will be a hard way.

I am wondering is there some dynamic casting way in C ?

I mean is there any way like:

```
struct TYPEANDFORMAT {
   enum DATATYPE type;
   char fmt[10];
};
struct DATA{
    enum DATATYPE type;
    char buff[8];
};


struct TYPEANDFORMAT TypeFmt[] = {
    {INT32, "%d"},
    {FLOAT, "%f"},
    {DOUBLE, "%lf"},
};

void printData (struct DATA *data) 
{
     printf(TypeFmt[data->type].fmt,  xxxx);  <===xxxx is the issue
}
```

I guess there should be some MACRO could work here.

Comment: Your `switch` does not work as expected: you should add a `break` after every `printf`.

Comment: Any reason you're not using an `union` for this?

Comment: If union is used here, I am afraid I have to use the switch way.I am using buff to see whether there is a dynamic casting way.

Comment: No, C doesn't have dynamic casting. I can think of many, many ways to do this in C++ but the C type system just doesn't work that way.

Comment: _I guess there should be some MACRO could work here._ you can not because it can not use the contents of an object of C in the macro.

Comment: Cannot you write directly into the char buffer the data with the correct representation in String format and print always the string?

Comment: writing such string also needs switch.

Comment: That code is seriously broken, and will invoke undefined behaviour. `char` buffer may not be correctly aligned for `int`, `float`, or `double`. Thus you must never cast `char` buffer to other pointer type and dereference it. Use `union` like in Otrebor's answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about using a union structure instead of a struct? That maybe would be better in your case.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type#Difference_between_Union_and_Structure

Define the union:

```
enum DATATYPE {INT32, FLOAT, DOUBLE};
typedef union myunion
{
     double D;
     float F;
     int I;
}MYUNION;

struct DATA{
    enum DATATYPE type;
    MYUNION d;
};
```

and after

```
switch (data.type) {
case INT32:
    printf("%d", data.d.I);
    break;
case FLOAT:
    printf("%f", data.d.F);
    break;
case DOUBLE:
    printf("%lf", data.d.D);
    break;
}
```